Question about signs of forces
I am trying to wrap my head around this derivation of a formula for the force of tension in a string undergoing wave motion:

I do not understand why $F_T$ is not considered positive in one direction and negative in the other. Also, why isn't $F_1$ pointing upwards and $F_2$ pointing downwards? Aren't they restoring forces? This is crucial to the derivation of the formula this leads up to, as it produces a difference quotient and ultimately a second derivative.

Please don't post pictures of text and equations, please transcribe the text, please use MathJax for mathematical expressions.

The presentation in this book is a pedagogical disaster (at least when it comes to this derivation).

There is a misprint in the textbook.
$\dfrac{F_2}{F_{\rm T}}={\LARGE\color{red}-} \left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right)_{x_2}$ should read $\dfrac{F_2}{F_{\rm T}}={\color{red}{\LARGE  +}} \left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right)_{x_2}$.
Read carefully the sentence leading up to the equation with negative slope used for one and only slope for the other.
Let $\hat j$ be the unit vector in the positive y-direction.
$\vec F_1 = F_{\rm T}\left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right)_{x_1}(-\hat j) $ and $\vec F_2 = F_{\rm T}\left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right)_{x_2}(+\hat j) $
Thus the resultant force on the element is $\vec F_1 + \vec F_2 = F_{\rm T}\left[\left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right)_{x_2} - \left(\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x} \right)_{x_1}\right ]\,\hat j$

Just found!
This edition of the textbook has the correct equation.


I do not understand why $F_T$ is not considered positive in one direction and negative in the other.

The author has implicitly assigned a tension $F_T$ to one end of the string segment and then used an equilibrium argument (the string is not accelerating horizontally) and a force balance to determine that the tension on the other side must also be $F_T$. Thus, there is indeed a force $F_T$ pulling on one end of the string and a force $-F_T$ pulling on the other end, regardless of the coordinate system.

Also, why isn't $F_1$ pointing upwards and $F_2$ pointing downwards?

You can draw forces in any direction you wish; of course, you may find in the solution that they’re negative, so you initially drew them “wrong.” But they’re not really wrong; reverse their direction and you’ll get positive numbers, which is the same solution.
Now, for a restoring force, I’d expect the force to be opposite the displacement. But the author hasn’t considered a constitutive law (yet); they’re just writing geometric relations.
